# Ruby: File size doesn't update with sentence starting with numbers

Tags: ruby, file, filesize

So I'm working with the twitter API of a soccer team, and I want to write to a file only the tweets tweeted during a live game, where the tweets are minute by minute events of the game. For instance, "25' This player got a yellow card" is an example of a tweet im looking for. All the live game tweets start with a minute, hence an integer, and I use the following regex to obtains such tweets, and write them to an text file

```
tweets = client.user_timeline('ManUtd', count: 3200)
tweets_file = File.open("tweets_file.txt", 'w')

tweets.each do |tweet| 
    if /[0-9]/.match(tweet.full_text[0])
        tweets_file.write(tweet.full_text + "\n")
    end
end
```

The thing is, my text file looks exactly like I want it to look like after I add in those tweets, but, the File.size() is 0, and I can't perform a code block on it either, that is, I cant do `File.Open(tweets_file).each`and evaluate each line or word in the file, because, as the file size indicates, there's nothing in it, but the actual file has a bunch of tweets written in it, so I'm pretty confused.

Can anyone shed some light on whats going on here?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, if I remove the regular expression, and simply add all the tweets form the timeline to my file, or if i replace the regex by [A-Z], then the File.Size works fine and i can use the each method on File.Open so it seems it has something to do with the integers at the beginning of a sentence

Comment: Could you add some sample data from `tweets`? Maybe `puts` out a few in the `each` loop...

Comment: This is what the tweets look like:
89' - Pizarro comes on for Banega - Sevilla's second change of the night. #MUFC #UCL
89' - MarcusRashford's free-kick from 30 yards out drifts just wide. #MUFC #UCL
86' - AnthonyMartial breaks away down the left, showing great pace, but no-one can get on the end of his cross. #MUFC #UCL
84' - A change for the hosts as Sandro replaces Muriel. #MUFC #UCL
83' - Lukaku finds the net with a tidy finish, but the no.9 is adjudged to have handled the ball. #MUFC #UCL
82' - Muriel tests with a powerful, low strike, but the #MUFC man is equal to it once again.

Comment: Did you close the file after writing and reopen it? Or did you rewind the file before reading?

Comment: Yes I rewinded the file before reading

Comment: What is actually happening "I can't" is not very explanatory `File.Open` is not a method and even `File.open(tweets_file).each` will just return an enumerator because you did not pass a block to `each`. This has nothing to do with the lines starting with a number and you have shown what is essentially "This code works why doesn't my other code I haven't posted?"

Comment: If it works with `/[A-Z]/` then the line begins with an upper case letter and not a number as you are implying. post some example of the `tweets` object and maybe someone will be more inclined (and actually capable of) helping

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a whitespace character or some kind of prefix string in the beginning of the tweet line. 
Use:

```
tweet.full_text.strip[0]
```

This will strip away whitespaces. Else you should find the prefix and strip IT out.

Comment: All the tweets start with something like "82' - blah blah", and there's no white space, simply starts with a number

Comment: What twitter client do you use?

Comment: tweets = client.user_timeline('ManUtd', count: 3200)

Comment: No, I mean gem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating the types of operations (and I'm pretty sure this would solve your problem), something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

tweets = client.user_timeline('ManUtd', count: 3200)

texts = tweets.map(&:full_text)

live_game_texts = texts.select do |text|
  text.start_with?(/\d/)
end

File.write('live_game_tweets.txt', live_game_texts.join("\n"))
```

Using `File.write` and *not* using `File.open` greatly simplifies the task since you don't have to worry about closing the file.